# Coding of a function f (relative to a ladder system $\overrightarrow{C}$)

Tags: logic, set-theory

Let $\overrightarrow{C}=\langle C_\delta \colon \delta \in \mbox{Lim}(\omega_1)\rangle$ be a ladder system on $\omega_1$. Let N $\subseteq M$ be countable subsets of $\gamma$ and $ \lbrace\omega_1, \alpha, \beta\rbrace \subseteq N$ such that for all, for all $\xi \in \lbrace \omega_1, \alpha, \beta, \gamma \rbrace$, sup$(N \cap \xi)<$ sup$(M \cap \xi)$.

Let $\alpha<\beta<\gamma$ be ordinals of cofinality $\omega_1$ in the interval $(\omega_1,\omega_2)$, and let $f$ be a function from $\omega_1$ to $2^\omega$, then we want to say *$(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ codes $f$ (relative to $\overrightarrow{C})$* if there is an $\omega_1$-club $\langle N_\xi \colon \xi < \omega_1 \rangle$ in $[\gamma]^{\aleph_0}$ such that

- $ \lbrace\omega_1, \alpha, \beta\rbrace \subseteq N_0 $;
- for all $ \nu < \omega_1 $ and all $ \xi \in \lbrace\omega_1, \alpha, \beta, \gamma\rbrace $, sup($N_\nu \cap \xi$)  is a limit ordinal;
- for all $ \nu_0 < \nu_1 < \omega_1 $ and all $ \xi \in \lbrace\omega_1, \alpha, \beta, \gamma\rbrace$, $ \mbox{sup}(N_{\nu_0} \cap \xi) < \mbox{sup}(N_{\nu_1} \cap \xi) $;
- for every limit $\nu < \omega_1$, there is a $ \nu_0 < \nu $ such that if $ \nu_0 < \xi < \nu $, then

$\Delta (\bar{s}(N_\xi, N_\nu), f(N_\nu \cap \omega_1)) \geqslant n(N_\xi,N_\nu)$.

$s$ and $n$ are functions computed using the parameters $\overrightarrow{C},\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$. For $r,s \in 2^{\leqslant \omega}$ let $\Delta (r,s)$ be the least $i$ such that $r(i) \neq s(i)$.

---

In the paper "The bounded proper forcing axiom and well orderings of the reals" by Caicedo/Velickovic this kind of coding is introduced and the question came up is:

If $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ codes two functions $f$ and $g$ relative to some $\overrightarrow{C}$, is there a club set of $\delta$ such that $f(\delta) = g(\delta)$ ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your notation, sorry. What does the second item in your list mean? What does the fourth item mean? Are you literally considering our coding, or rather a variant of it?

Comment: Sorry I had two typos in those items. I also added the the delta function. This is not exactly your your coding but just a minor variation. As in your paper $n(N,M) = \vert {\omega_1}^{\bar{N}} \cap 
C_{{\omega_1}^{\bar{M}}} \vert$ describes the height of N in M with respect to $\overrightarrow{C}$, where $\omega_1^{\bar{N}}$ and $\omega_1^{\bar{M}}$ describe the respective order-types of $N \cap \omega_1$ and $M \cap \omega_1$. Also with minor variation let $ s(N,M) = s_{\alpha, \beta}^{\overrightarrow{C}}(N,M) = o(x,y,z) $ if the lenghth of the oscillation of $x,y,z$ is at least $n(n,M)$.

Comment: For a binary sequence $s$ of finite length, $\bar{s}$ describes the sequence of the same length $l$ with the digits reversed, $\bar{s}(i) = s(l-i)$.

Comment: Let's see... $n(N_\xi,N_\nu)\to\infty$ as $\xi\to\nu$, right? You still have not said what ${s^{\vec C}}_{\alpha,\beta}(N,M)$ is (what are $x,y,z$?) but, presumably these things are designed to cohere in the sense that, fixing an appropriate $\nu$, the reals $\bar s (N_\xi,N_\nu)$ converge as $\xi\to\nu$. If that is the case, then yes, if $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ codes both $f$ and $g$ relative to $\vec C$, then $f$ and $g$ agree on a club. At least in our case, the coding was designed to have this kind of agreement. (This is pointed out in our Remark 2.)

Comment: Well, $x,y,z$ are sets defined as $x = \lbrace \vert \pi (\xi) \cap C_{\alpha_M} \vert \colon \xi \in \alpha \cap N \rbrace$ and $y$ and $z$ similarly with in the definition of the set $z$, $\xi$ is an element of $N$. I see what you mean with your Remark 2, but is it that clear that it follows directly from the definitions of this coding? Sorry I am still struggling to see.